# Singular or Plural in a list?

Tags: nouns, grammatical-number, lists

When naming multiple things in the form in a list is it singular or plural?

i.e.

> The charts can be found in Appendix A, B, and C.

or

> The charts can be found in Appendices A, B, and C.

Comment: Google Books claims about 9280 instances of [in appendix 1 and 2](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22in+appendix+1+and+2%22), but I only see that exact string once in the 12 results it *actually* returns when I scroll through them. On the other hand, [in **appendices** 1 and 2](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22in+appendix+1+and+2%22) claims only about 6260 instances, but that string occurs in each of the first 20 results, and I've no reason to suppose the second estimated result count is also wildly inaccurate. Having said that, both versions are fine by me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were to skip listing the specific appendices, you wouldn't write *The charts can be found in the appendix* -- there is clearly more than one.  You would write *The charts can be found in the appendices.*

So why would it be any different if you list them?

> *The charts can be found in Appendix A.*
>
> *The charts can be found in Appendices A, B, and C.*

Hope this helps !

Comment: I think what might be confusing me is that there is 1 chart in Appendix A, 1 chart in Appendix B, and 1 chart in Appendix C.
There only being one item in each appendix is making me second guess which noun to use. That and the fact that when I say both versions out loud, they both sound acceptable.

Comment: That there is only one chart in each location is irrelevant; you're talking about all of them.  You could say _The charts can be found in Appendix A, Appendix B, and Appendix C_, in which case each "Appendix" is singular, but if you're going to lump them together as A, B, and C, it needs to be _Appendices_.  Perhaps the reason _Appendix_ sounds okay is that it would be okay if you were to say _The charts can be found in Appendix A, the public library, and my brother's mailbox._  Since they're all appendices, you can group them together but then they're plural.